# Another WPF "binding not updating" issue

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here is my custom control which is a kind of simple progress bar:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace eg.BJM.Controls
{
    public class HorizontalBarGauge : Canvas
    {
        public HorizontalBarGauge()
        {
            IsSigned = true;
            MinValue = -100;
            MaxValue = 100;
            Value = 25;
            MarkerValue = -1;
            BorderColor = Colors.Black;
            MarkerColor = Colors.Red;
            BarColor = Colors.SkyBlue;
            BaseColor = Colors.DodgerBlue;
            ValueColor = Colors.White;
        }

        #region Dependecy Properties

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(int), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MinValue", typeof(int), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxValue", typeof(int), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkerValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MarkerValue", typeof(int), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MarkerColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MarkerColor", typeof(Color), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BaseColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BaseColor", typeof(Color), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BarColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BarColor", typeof(Color), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BorderColor", typeof(Color), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty BorderThicknessProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("BorderThickness", typeof(double), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSignedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsSigned", typeof(bool), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ShowValue", typeof(bool), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ValueColor", typeof(Color), typeof(HorizontalBarGauge));

    #endregion

    [Description("Determines whether the bar shows [min,max] or [-max,+max]")]
    public bool IsSigned
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue( IsSignedProperty ); }    
        set
        {
            SetValue( IsSignedProperty, value );
            if (value)
            {
                MinValue = -MaxValue;
            }
            else
            {
                MinValue = 0;
            }
            reassertValues();
            InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the current value to show.")]
    public int Value
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue( ValueProperty, value );
            InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the minimum value to show.")]
    public int MinValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MinValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MinValueProperty, value);
            reassertValues();
            InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the maximum value to show.")]
    public int MaxValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MaxValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            value = Math.Max(value, 1);
            SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value);
            reassertValues();
            InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the marker value to show. Negative => no marker.")]
    public int MarkerValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MarkerValueProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value);
            reassertValues();
            InvalidateVisual();
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the color of the marker.")]
    public Color MarkerColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(MarkerColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MarkerColorProperty, value);
            Brush penBrush = new SolidColorBrush( value );
            _markerPen = new Pen( penBrush, 3 );
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the value text color.")]
    public Color ValueColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(ValueColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueColorProperty, value);
            _textBrush = new SolidColorBrush(value);
        }
    }


    [Description("Get/set the base color.")]
    public Color BaseColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BaseColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BaseColorProperty, value);
            _bodyBrush = new SolidColorBrush( value );
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the bar color.")]
    public Color BarColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BarColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BarColorProperty, value);
            _barBrush = new SolidColorBrush( value );
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the border color.")]
    public Color BorderColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BorderColorProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BorderColorProperty, value);
            var brush = new SolidColorBrush( value );
            _borderPen = new Pen( brush, BorderThickness );
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set the border thickness.")]
    public double BorderThickness
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(BorderThicknessProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BorderThicknessProperty, value);
            var brush = new SolidColorBrush( BorderColor );
            _borderPen = new Pen( brush, value );
        }
    }

    [Description("Get/set whether values are displayed in the control.")]
    public bool ShowValue
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue( ShowValueProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( ShowValueProperty, value );}
    }

    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        base.OnRender(drawingContext);

        // Background.
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(_bodyBrush, null, _rectangle);

        // Bar.
        int value = Value;
        if (value != 0)
        {
            Rect barRect;
            if (IsSigned)
            {
                double frac = Convert.ToDouble(value)/Convert.ToDouble(MaxValue*2);
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    barRect = new Rect(_rectangle.Width/2-frac*_rectangle.Width, 0, _rectangle.Width/2, _rectangle.Height);
                }
                else
                {
                    barRect = new Rect( _rectangle.Width/2, 0, frac*_rectangle.Width, _rectangle.Height );
                }

                drawingContext.DrawRectangle( _barBrush, null, barRect );
            }
            else
            {
                double x = (_rectangle.Width*value)/(MaxValue - MinValue);
                if (x > 0)
                {
                    barRect = new Rect( 0, 0, x, _rectangle.Height );
                    drawingContext.DrawRectangle( _barBrush, null, barRect );
                }
            }
        }

        // Marker.
        if (MarkerValue >= 0)
        {
            if (IsSigned)
            {
                double frac = Convert.ToDouble( MarkerValue )/Convert.ToDouble( MaxValue );
                double markerX1 = 0.5*_rectangle.Width*(1 + frac);
                Point p0 = new Point( markerX1, 0 );
                Point p1 = new Point( markerX1, _rectangle.Height );
                drawingContext.DrawLine( _markerPen, p0, p1 );
                double markerX2 = 0.5*_rectangle.Width*(1 - frac);
                Point p2 = new Point( markerX2, 0 );
                Point p3 = new Point( markerX2, _rectangle.Height );
                drawingContext.DrawLine( _markerPen, p2, p3 );
            }
            else
            {
                double markerX = (_rectangle.Width*MarkerValue)/(MaxValue - MinValue);
                Point p0 = new Point( markerX, 0 );
                Point p1 = new Point( markerX, _rectangle.Height );
                drawingContext.DrawLine( _markerPen, p0, p1 );
            }
        }

        // Border.
        drawingContext.DrawRectangle(null, _borderPen, _rectangle);

        // Text.
        if (ShowValue)
        {
            FormattedText text = new FormattedText( value.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                FlowDirection.LeftToRight, s_typeface, 12, _textBrush );
            Point pos = new Point( (_rectangle.Width - text.Width)/2, (_rectangle.Height - text.Height)/2 );
            drawingContext.DrawText( text, pos );
        }
    }

    protected override void OnRenderSizeChanged(SizeChangedInfo sizeInfo)
    {
        base.OnRenderSizeChanged(sizeInfo);
        _rectangle = new Rect( sizeInfo.NewSize );
        InvalidateVisual();
    }

    private int clamp(int value)
    {
        return (value < MinValue ? MinValue : value > MaxValue ? MaxValue : value);
    }

    private void reassertValues()
    {
        // Make sure max and min are correct.
        int oldMin = MinValue;
        int newMin = oldMin;

        int oldMax = MaxValue;
        int newMax = oldMax;

        if (oldMin > oldMax)
        {
            newMin = oldMax;
            newMax = oldMin;
        }

        if (newMin != oldMin)
        {
            SetValue(MinValueProperty, newMin);
        }

        if (newMax != oldMax)
        {
            SetValue(MaxValueProperty, newMax);
        }

        // Make sure value is in [min,max].
        int oldValue = Value;
        int newValue = clamp(oldValue);
        if (newValue != oldValue)
        {
            Value = newValue;
        }

        // Make sure marker is correctly placed.
        int marker = MarkerValue;
        if (marker >= 0)
        {
            int newMarker = clamp(marker);
            if (newMarker != marker)
            {
                SetValue(MarkerValueProperty, newMarker);
            }
        }
    }

    private Pen _borderPen;
    private Pen _markerPen;
    private Brush _barBrush;
    private Brush _bodyBrush;
    private Rect _rectangle;
    private Brush _textBrush;

    private static readonly Typeface s_typeface = new Typeface( "Verdana" );
}
```

}

Here is the XAML which binds to it:

```
        <controls:HorizontalBarGauge Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                                 Margin="8" Width="130" Height="18"
                                 IsSigned="False"
                                 MinValue="0"
                                 MaxValue="100"
                                 BorderThickness="2"
                                 BorderColor="MidnightBlue"
                                 ShowValue="True"
                                 Value="{Binding StepperPosition}"
                                 />
```

When the controls initialize, the control shows the correct value. But when I change the "StepperPosition" property in later code, nothing changes. Breakpointing the code shows the ValueProperty setter does not get called even though the StepperPosition does and fires the OnPropertyChanged( "StepperPosition" ). The INPC is in a base class. So I think I've ruled out the usual causes of the binding not refreshing, and am now a bit stumped.

---

Monday. Right, moved on a bit. Can now refresh the visuals by hooking in to the DepedencyPropertyChanged callbacks. @HighCore this is what they look like:

[image: Bars]

The bar has two modes: speed (which needs to be +/-) and position (which is always +ve). The red line in the speed gauge shows a max speed set elsewhere. They are updated in near-real-time as they are indicators for stepper motor state.

Comment: `Value` is a DP. It's not going to call your setter when Value is updated through a `Binding`. The getter and setter you define in your code are merely "helpers for you" and not used by the underlying framework. Hence why you should not be doing anything in the property getter/setter helpers of a DP. Thus your breakpoint mode of diagnosing updates are kinda useless. If you want to detect changes assign a propertychangedcallback when you define your DP. Now as for your issue have you tried setting `Value="{Binding StepperPosition, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"`???

Comment: So Value is in the UI element class, which is a read-only visual. Ie I can't change data model state with it, it simply shows me a visual representation. So the TwoWay idea must surely (?) be irrelevant because I am changing StepperPosition which is in the ViewModel. Since Value is bound to that integer, I would expect it to change upon OnPropertyChanged( "StepperPosition" ), and thereforew Value to change, invalidating the control and causing a redraw.

Comment: @JulianGold you are placing too much data in the UI, where it does not belong. Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: Thanks @HighCore, I am home from work now, will take this up again on Monday.

Comment: Right so now I am fresh, is my understanding correct that the modification of Value is through some framework magic and not via the setter I supply, and that in order to refresh the visual, I need to hook in a UIPropertyMetadata callback in the Value dependency property?

Comment: @HighCore I edited my OP to give you an idea of how the widget should look. Your input would be appreciated!

Comment: You need set all your initial value in PropertyMetadata when you registering dependency properties and move logics in setter into ValueChangedCallback in PropertyMetadata.